# Workflow status change

Tags: designer-workflow

I have a field `status` in my list. The status field has three values as `Approved`, `Rejected` and `Pending`. Whenever these values get changed it should trigger a mail. And if it is approved it should store the records in Log file. Can somebody help? Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this link: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/cfda237a-4a48-42f3-968f-e2b1d19f488d/create-a-workflow-so-what-the-value-in-the-field-called-status-changes-an-email-be-sent-a-specific?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious